# Get the current Task instance in an async method body

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

If I have an async method body like so -

```
public async Task GetSomething() {

    await SendText("hi");
    await SendImage("bla.bmp");

}
```

How can I get the Task object before it is returned to the user when the await kicks in

ie..

```
public async Task GetSomething() {

    myTasks.Add(Task.Current);
    await SendText("hi");
    await SendImage("bla.bmp");

    //some processing

}
```

so that somewhere else I can do

```
 await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
 Console.WriteLine("All tasks complete");
```

This is so that I can wait for all tasks to complete before shutting down

Comment: What are the signatures for `SendText` and `SendImage`?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. That's just some dummy code to show that GetSomething performs multiple child operations. Replace those with a Thread.Sleep(50000) if it makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes it does. The methods can return `void`, `Task` and `Task<T>`, if it is `Task` or `Task<T>` you can refactor the code. You can get task objects and add them to a single array.

Comment: But it's not the inner Tasks I wish to collect, it's the top-level Tasks I want. There could be 10+ inner tasks, I do not wish to add them to the list every time i start one.. that would be messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not directly possible as the language does not have a facility to access the "current" task.

There is a workaround though: Wrap your async method in another method. This *other* method can get hold of the task once the async method returns (which happens approximately at the first await point).

In all cases I recommend letting the caller add the async Task to your list, not the async method itself. This is useful even from an encapsulation point of view.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I don't know whether this means I'm doing something wrong or if such a use-case hasn't been thought of before. I'd have thought that keeping track of all asynchronous methods would be quite common. I guess I'm going to have to uglify my code by wrapping it in an inner function.