# An asynchronous counter which can be awaited on

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a connection class which has several async methods such as SendText, SendImage etc.

The connection class has a Disconnect method, and when it is called I have to be careful not to start changing the inner state of the class before all async methods have completed execution.

I believe a good way to achieve this is to simply keep a running total of the number of operations in execution, and then when I want to Disconnect I can simply set Disconnecting = true and then wait for the count to reach 0

I'm thinking of something along the lines of this

```
class ReferenceCounter
{
    void Increment();

    void Decrement();

    async Task WaitForCounterToReachZero();
}
```

Then when an async operation starts I could do

```
refCounter.Increment();
```

When it ends

```
refCounter.Decrement();
```

and inside the Disconnect method

```
disconnecting = true;
taskCancellationSource.Cancel();
await refCounter.WaitForCounterToReachZero();
Cleanup();
```

Are there any built in .NET classes like this?

Or more importantly for me, is there a better way of doing this?

If it was synchronous code it would be as simple as

```
lock (thisLock)
{
    while (counter > 0)
        Monitor.Wait(thisLock);
}
```

I just found the built in CountdownEvent class which does the same thing, but it has no async Wait method nor does it have any events, so I'd have to block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, assuming you'll never increment again *after* you make it 0, you could do something like this:

```
public class Latch
{
    private int count = 0;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs =
        new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public void Increment()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)
        {
            tcs.TrySetValue(null);
        }
    }

    public Task Task { get { return tcs.Task; } }
}
```

Then you can await `someLatch.Task`. Alternatively, you could make the latch itself awaitable:

```
public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
{
    return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter();
}
```

You should probably consider how you want to guard against the "count rises after getting down to 0" aspect thuogh - think about what you'd want it to do. (In the code above, once the TCS's value has been set, further awaits will complete immediately.)

Comment: That's a nice elegant implementation of what I had in mind. I don't have to worry about the count rising after getting down to 0 because the _disconnecting bool will prevent further operations. That aside, do you think this is a good way of handling such a scenario? My concern is that the reason such a class does not exist in the framework is because such a thing would be frowned upon. Have you found yourself in a similar situation and done things differently?

Comment: @NoPyGod: It's not quite clear whether you really need a count - you talk about having a load of asynchronous methods... do they all return `Task` or something similar? If so, `Task.WhenAll` is your friend. You can keep a pool of outstanding tasks, and just await `Task.WhenAll` to wait until they've all completed.

Comment: I could do that, but inside the async method body I have no way of accessing the task which is going to be returned. To achieve what you're suggesting I would have to wrap an inner method which returns the Task which I can then add to a pool of outstanding tasks. This seems more contrived than what I'm suggesting but if that's a recommended practice for situations like these then I'd prefer to do it that way. Given your obvious expertise in the area, I'm very interested in your opinion.

Comment: I posted a question yesterday about retrieving the current task from inside an async method body but it didn't get much love - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303003/get-the-current-task-instance-in-an-async-method-body

Comment: @NoPyGod: If it's a pain to do that, then this latch approach should be okay, I think.

Comment: FYI, Stephen Toub has an [`AsyncCountdownEvent` on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266930.aspx) and it's also a [part of my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncCountdownEvent).

Comment: @StephenCleary: I think the requirements are a *little* different here in that it needs to be able to count up as well as down. I suspect there's a way of transforming the problem, admittedly.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Right. The version in my library does allow counting up and down until it reaches zero.