# Is it possible to await the calling task?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is there a way to await the calling task?

```
Async Function DoStuff() As Task
    StartDoingOtherStuff()

    ' Doing stuff
End Function

Async Function StartDoingOtherStuff() As Task
    ' Doing stuff

    Await callingTask

    ' Finish up
End Function
```

Note: I want to paralize the task, because it involves uploading a file to multiple destinations. But I want to await the calling task, to delete the file after all uploads are complete.

Comment: You can only await a task you have a reference to

Comment: Can‘t I pass the task itself on calling the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current Task instance in an async method body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303003/get-the-current-task-instance-in-an-async-method-body)

Comment: @VisualVincent That‘s C#. But yeah, I think I get it. It‘s not possible.

Comment: The answer doesn't include any code so it applies to most .NET languages which support Async/Await. Still, C# and VB.NET are so equal that you can usually convert between them.

Comment: _"I think I get it. It‘s not possible"_ - The answer doesn't say that it's _impossible_, but it has some restrictions to it. You have to use a lambda expression and assign the resulting task to a variable which you then pass back to the lambda itself. However, for this to work you need to have at least one `Await` before you can use the task.

Comment: @VisualVincent lambda? I read it as I need another method that wraps both. That‘s what I tried to avoid.

Comment: A [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) is an inline method, so it _is_ another method. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent I see. I didn‘t use lambdas that much yet. Could you give me an example how that would look like in this case?

Comment: Sure! I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on usr's answer to [*Get the current Task instance in an async method body*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14303179), you can do this:

```
Private Async Function DoStuff() As Task
    'Capture the resulting task in a variable.
    Dim t As Task = (
        Async Function() As Task
            Console.WriteLine("DoStuff()")

            'First await. Required in order to return the task to 't'.
            Await Task.Delay(1)

            'Disable warnings:
            '    "Because this call is not awaited (...)"
            '    "Variable 't' is used before it has been assigned a value (...)"

#Disable Warning BC42358, BC42104

            'Call other method.
            DoOtherStuff(t)

#Enable Warning BC42358, BC42104

            'Simulate process.
            Await Task.Delay(3000)
        End Function
    ).Invoke()

    'Await if needed.
    Await t
End Function

Private Async Function DoOtherStuff(ByVal ParentTask As Task) As Task
    Console.WriteLine("DoOtherStuff()")

    'Await parent task.
    Await ParentTask

    Console.WriteLine("DoStuff() finished!")
End Function
```

By using a lambda expression you can capture the current task and then pass it to itself. `Await Task.Delay(1)` is required in order for the async method to return its task so that it can be set to the variable. However, you can remove it if you already have another await before `DoOtherStuff()` is called.

Comment: What is the Invoke() for?

Comment: @Fox : `Invoke()` executes the function and returns its return value (in this case the `Task`). It's basically equivalent to doing: `FunctionName()`. Without calling it you would just have a pointer to a function.

Comment: I see. It works. But I think just wrapping it in an method is the easier way way then. Thanks for showing.

Comment: @Fox : Whatever suits you the best :). This is for if you want to avoid having another method in your class.

Comment: @Fox : The `#Disable` and `#Enable Warning` can be omitted if you'd like to shorten the code. They're just there to stop the compiler from displaying warnings about our code's behaviour (which we don't need since we're doing this intentionally).

Comment: Yea I know about that.